# Android cocos2d removing a sprite after animation

Tags: android, animation, sprites, cocos2d, spritesheet

I have an object going across the screen with an animation using the following code:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().addSpriteFrames("ninjastar.plist");
CCSpriteSheet projectileSheet = CCSpriteSheet.spriteSheet("ninjastar.png");
addChild(projectileSheet);
ArrayList<CCSpriteFrame> projectileSprites = new ArrayList<CCSpriteFrame>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    projectileSprites.add(CCSpriteFrameCache.spriteFrameByName("ninjastar" + i + ".png"));
}

CCAnimation projectileAnimation = CCAnimation.animation("throw", 0.1f, projectileSprites);
CCSprite projectile = CCSprite.sprite(projectileSprites.get(0));
CCAction projectileAction = CCRepeatForever.action(CCAnimate.action(projectileAnimation, false));
projectile.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(winSize.width + (projectile.getContentSize().width / 2.0f), actualY));
    actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(actualDuration, CGPoint.ccp(-projectile.getContentSize().width / 2.0f + 320, actualY));
projectileSheet.addChild(projectile);
projectile.setTag(1);
_projectiles.add(projectile);
CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "spriteMoveFinished");
CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(actionMove, actionMoveDone);
projectile.runAction(actions);
projectile.runAction(projectileAction);
```

I'm using "spriteMoveFinished" to remove the sprite once it is done going across the screen:

```
public void spriteMoveFinished(Object sender) {
CCSprite sprite = (CCSprite)sender;
_projectiles.remove(sprite);
sprite.stopAllActions();
removeChild(sprite, true);
}
```

However, when the sprite gets to the end of the screen it just stays stuck there on the last frame. How do I remove it completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `projectile` is added to `projectileSheet`, but being removed from current layer or scene, rather than removing from `projectileSheet`. The last line of `spriteMoveFinished` should be

```
projectileSheet.removeChild(sprite, true);
```

or better use

```
sprite.removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
```